# How to archive Outlook mails based on time and size?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We have to migrate a lot of mail from an imap server to an exchange server.

The sizes of the boxes in the exchange server are limited to 2GB while a lot of our imap boxes are much bigger than that. We deal with this by archiving all mail older than 1 year and keep it as a local archive available.
However some users receive so much attachments that they fill 2GB in 2 months, for them we want to archive all mail older than 1 year or with attechments bigger then for instance 2MB.

It is easy to make a search and find all mail which complies to these criteria, however we want to preserve the (very large) folder structure.

Anyone a idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Manual method is search by date "older than " criteria and move to a new folder. Archive , then delete from main folder.

I remember doing this on XP client and perhaps auto archive is now avail.
File /data base compression may be possible from File properties within Outlook.

This is a 32bit file size limit. for that OS.

Lots of RAM needed >>4gb fast searches on client. I had a few Outlook .dat files but it worked on single .dat file outlook folder searches.
To preserve folder structure , other tricks may be involved, like dupe then selective delete instead of the reverse.  (sorry for lack of clarity or simplicity, that's why I dropped MSO towards gmail server.